# where is pageProps in nextjs v13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

in earlier version of next, we have this file `pages/_app.js` which by default gives us this :
[image]

we have `pageProps` key in this react component. when i tried nextjs v13, i can't seem to find it.

my question is where is that (in this case, in which file) `pageProps` existed in nextjs v13?

and the other related question is, in the earlier version of nextjs we can do something like
`<p.Component {...p.pageProps} />` in the `pages/app.js`
notice we can pass the pageProps because we're using a tag.

but in the latest version, you can only use something like
`{p.children}` which means you cannot pass props anything.
i tried to make it `<p.children />` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `pageProps` doesn't exist in the `app` folder (but you can still use the `pages` folder in Next.js 13). I'd recommend going through the [Migrating from `pages` to `app` documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-from-pages-to-app) for details.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts)

> Passing data between a parent layout and its children is not possible.
> However, you can fetch the same data in a route more than once, and
> React will automatically dedupe the requests without affecting
> performance.

I saw that some people suggest doing it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
export default function Layout(props) {

 props.params.data = "some-data";

  return (
        <div>
          {props.children}
        </div>
  );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Next.js `Metadata API` to Set and Consume `pageProps`

Next.js provides a `Metadata API` that can be leveraged to address this issue. You can set `pageProps` using the `metadata constant`. Define your metadata like this:

```
// metadata.js
export const metadata = {
  other: {
    custom: [
      JSON.stringify({
        key: value,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Then, you can consume it within your component:

```
// YourComponent.js

const pageProps = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector("meta[name='custom']").getAttribute("content")
);

// Now, 'pageProps' contains the parsed metadata
```